# JSON Path grab key and value

Tags: json, pentaho, jsonpath

I have some json here, and I need to use JSONPath (with Pentaho) to parse it out, and give me the key and value. I have used $.. but that just returned the value with no keys, which is pretty much useless. Is there any way to get both the key and value?

```
[
    {
        "avatar": "...",
        "name": "j@example.com",
        "email": "...",
        "id": 82
    },
    {
        "avatar": "...",
        "name": "admin@example.com",
        "email": "admin@example.com",
        "id": 81
    }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out. Had to create one JSON input with $..* and another for each individual id I needed to parse out.